# C++ not deducting correctly using guide

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass {
public:
    using container = std::vector<T>;

    container  buffer;
public:
    SomeClass(T elem): buffer({elem})  {
    }
};


SomeClass(char const*) -> SomeClass<std::string>;

int main() {

    std::cout << typeid(SomeClass<char const*>).name() << std::endl;

    SomeClass a("test");

    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I specified a guide to convert from `char const*` to `std::string` as I saw in an example, but the output gives me

`class SomeClass<char const *\>`

`class SomeClass<char const *>`

I would expect both types to be instantiated to std::string, not char const*

How would I change this code to produce that output?

Comment: What compiler are you using? It does the right thing in gcc and clang.

Comment: I'm using the visual studio compiler (as a clion toolchain)

Comment: The first line of output does not use class template argument deduction, so the deduction guide isn't used. The second one *should* specialize with `std::string`.

Comment: Are you ecpecting `typeid(SomeClass<char const*>).name()` to be a `SomeClass<std::string>`?

Comment: @NathanOliver As Quentin commented, I was mistaken for that one, I miss-understood how the guide works slightly. But I would still expect the second typeid() to be SomeClass<std::string>

Comment: Latest version of msvc works fine. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/amUwft

Comment: What version of MSVS are you using?  I get `typeid(a).name()` is a `SomeClass<std::string>` with version 15.8.7 compiling against `/std:latest`

Comment: [This code works as expected](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PeB8Fuy4H4cedq2X)